# Toggle Switch to exec shell script

Tags: php, jquery, shell

I am trying to make some Toggle switch: when its off it will send some command (`IN1`), and if its on it will be send another command (`IN2`)

Commands are send via shell script

What I'm using is a button like this:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['IN1']) {
  echo shell_exec("sudo sh /home/cubie/phpdemo/IN1.sh");
}
?>

<a href="?IN1=true">IN1</a>
```

but i found this:
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

and I want to use it. But how can I do same but with the Switch

`IN1on`

`IN1off`

===

some edit
ok now i got it. 
i have set this up

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />


<?php

function get_in1_status() {
    return shell_exec('cat  /sys/class/gpio/gpio19_pg7/value');
    /* return (boolean) */ }
/* return TRUE if you object is active ; else return FALSE */

function set_all_off() {
    shell_exec('java -cp /home/cubie/demo/ allinone 2'); 
    }

function set_all_on() {
    shell_exec('java -cp /home/cubie/demo/ allinone 1'); 
    }   

$current_value = get_in1_status();

?>


<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" 
  <?php echo ($current_value == true ) ? 'checked="checked"' : null; ?>
  <?php
    if( $current_value == true ) {
    set_all_on();
    }
    else if($current_value == false){
    set_all_off();
    }
  ?>
  >
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
```

Comment: You really don't want to have a web-accessible script executing with sudo. Instead, change the file permission on IN1.sh so that php can execute it.

Comment: its not a big problem for me because its just for me its for a home use in a local network, but the problem now how can i make it work with the Switch and for sure later on if i finish it it will be with other command

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a toggle button, you need to get **the current value of your object**.
Do you have any way to get it ?

```
<?php

function get_in1_status() { /* return (boolean) */ }
/* return TRUE if you object is active ; else return FALSE */

function set_in1_on() { shell_exec('sudo sh /home/cubie/phpdemo/IN1.sh'); }

$current_value = get_in1_status();

?>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" <?php echo ($current_value == true ) ? 'checked="checked"' : null; ?>>
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
```

> On the get_in1_status, you could for example call another .sh code that will return the state of your service. You could aloso store this value on a file or a database, no anything else that will allow you to get the true/false value.

---

> **Question:** ok great. for the current value i can get it in some other file
>   /sys/class/gpio/gpio19_pg7/value
>   in the value it will be 0 or 1 so how can i do that ? i want to exec a
>   script if the switch off and another if its swich on. – *Anmar Mashat*

Of course you can :)
If the value is on a file, try for example:

```
<?php function get_in1_status() {
  return shell_exec('cat  /sys/class/gpio/gpio19_pg7/value');
}
```

In PHP, 1 is equal to `true` (in fact, any value different of **0**, **false** or **null** is equal to true).
If you want to have an explicit boolean value to can force `$result = (boolean) 1;` so `$result` will be equal to `true` :)

If you want a specific text:

```
<?php
echo (get_in1_status() ? 'on': 'off'); // will return 'on' or 'off' value
echo (get_in1_status() == true ? 'on': 'off'); // Same. will return 'on' or 'off' value
echo get_in1_status(); // will return the content on the value
echo (boolean) get_in1_status(); // will return 1 or 0


if( get_in1_status() ) {
    // if yes
}
else {
    // if no
}
?>
```

Now, you just need to choose.

---

**Based on your work:** Almost :) But the logic of the swith is not correct. You need to check the value and change it with an event (ex: catch a page refresh, value via _GET)

See:

> If the code does not works, try to comment the first return on the get in1_status function and uncomment the second one :)
>   If it's still not working ... try another shell comand. What is `value` ? a file ? a program ? Use cat/echo or execute the line directly.

Your functions:

```
<?php

function get_in1_status() {
    return shell_exec('cat  /sys/class/gpio/gpio19_pg7/value');
    //return file_get_contents('/sys/class/gpio/gpio19_pg7/value'); // solution 2
}

function set_all_off() {
    shell_exec('java -cp /home/cubie/demo/ allinone 2');
}

function set_all_on() {
    shell_exec('java -cp /home/cubie/demo/ allinone 1'); 
}
```

Now, the event. Whet I catch a 'in1' _GET parameter, I run the logic of switching.
More php code:

```
<?php

// change the value
if( isset($_GET['in1']) ) { // if url contains 'in1' parameter
  switch($_GET['in1']) {
    case 'on': // ?in1=on
      set_all_off();
      break;

    case 'off': // ?in1=off
      set_all_on();
      break;

    default:  // ?in1 or ?in1=anything_else
        if( get_in1_status() )
          set_all_off(); // if true=on  -> switch off
        else
          set_all_on();  // if true=off -> switch ofn
      break;
  }
}

// get the current value
$current_value = get_in1_status();

?>
```

And the HTML: (This is an example. Here I use an `<a />` element. *Tips: Submit your form to change the value or do it dynamically with ajax for example*)

```
<a href="?in1">
  Default (switch):
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" <?php echo ($current_value) ? 'checked="checked"' : null; ?> />
    <div class="slider round"></div>
  </label>
</a>

<br />

<a href="?ini=on">On</a> <a href="?ini=off">On</a>
```

(Code not tested)

Comment: ok great. for the current value i can get it in some other file 
/sys/class/gpio/gpio19_pg7/value

Comment: in the value it will be 0 or 1 so how can i do that ? i want to exec a script if the switch off and another if its swich on.

Comment: can it be 1/0 not turn/false ?

Comment: I edited my previous answer :) Just read the content of the file. I used a shell_exec comand but if you jsut want to read the content you have another functions as `file_get_contents()` or `file()`.

Comment: i have done this you can chake it up. but it didn't work, how can i exec the methode or a script from the button if its turn on a command will send or if it turn off another command will send